Iterate over sublists and take item at given index
I'm struggling on how to select items at the same index from two sublists using zip function
List1 = [ [ 6, 7, 8 ] , [ 9, 10, 11 ] ]
List2 = [ [ A, B, C ] , [ D, E, F ] ]

for i, j in zip(List1, List2):
    out1 = [ ]
    out2 = [ ]
    
    for c, v in zip( range(len(i)), range(len(j))):
        # I'm struggling here
        if c =1 and v = 1:
            out1.append( c[i] )
            out2.append( v[j] )

Expect result:
out1 = [7, 10]
out2 = [ ]


You treat c and v as numbers at first, but then do indexing operations on them, e.g., c[i] and v[j]. That's contradictory.

if c =1 and v = 1: should get a syntax error. = is assignment, == is comparison. So this is obviously not your actual code.

You also need to quote the strings in List2.

@jjramsey I guess they meant i[c] and j[v].

c and v will always be the same, do you really need both variables? It's equivalent to for c in range(min(len(i), len(j))):

I think you meant i[c] and j[c]. That said, this might be faster: out1 = [L[1] for L in L1]

There's absolutely no need for the inner zip here. Why is the expected output for out2 an empty list?

I think you want something like this? just take index 1 of each list, you don't need to do a second inner iteration. You also need to take care of the scope/indentation of out1/out2, with the current code it is essentially resetting those two output variables on every sublist instead of being something added to during each iteration.  You also might want to do something like checking each inner list is at least of length 2, but that's just another inner list.
List1 = [[6, 7, 8], [9, 10, 11]]
List2 = [["A", "B", "C"], ["D", "E", "F"]]
out1 = []
out2 = []
for a, b in zip(List1, List2):
    out1.append(a[1])
    out2.append(b[1])

output:
>>> out1
[7, 10]
>>> out2
['B', 'E']

You can also do this with list comprehensions
out3 = [sublist[1] for sublist in List1]
out4 = [sublist[1] for sublist in List2]

output:
>>> out3
[7, 10]
>>> out4
['B', 'E']


here my real problem
I've a main list loops with 4 sublists
loops
I've defined two other lists, loop1 and loop2, from which I want to take the line at index 1 from each to create another line, but I'm getting an error that says:

unindexable object

here the part of my code
loop1 = loops[0]

loop2 = loops[2]

for i, j in zip(loop1, loop2):
    line1 = i[1]
    line2 = j[1]

OUT = line1, line2

Is there another way to eterate over the main list loops without create the lists loop1 and loop2 to get what I want?
